# Ruby On Rails - Grape - ActiveRecord from JSON body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, ruby-grape

What is the correct way to create a new `ActiveRecord` from json using grape? Do I use `attr_accessible` in my User model to avoid `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` or how does it work?

I'm using Rails 4.0.4 and ruby 1.9.3p545.

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #maybe attr_accessible??
end
```

**POST Body**

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

**Grape**

```
version :v1, :format => :json
...
post do
  #what goes here?
  user = User.new params
  user.save!
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way would be not to use mass-assignment, and go through assigning each of the params piecemeal. Like it's done in the [Grape README](https://github.com/intridea/grape#parameters) examples.

If you feel strongly about using mass-assignment, you could use the [protected_attributes gem](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) to get the attr_accessible functionality.

But if you have so many params that you're tempted to use mass-assignment, that could be a smell that you need to refactor the resource being created.

Comment: I've solved it by using: `def permitted_params
@permitted_params ||= declared(params, include_missing: false)
end`
In a helper, is this bad in any way?

Comment: It's not the amount of parameters that is the issue, it is the constant re-factoring that is killing my devtime. Once I've reached a point of satisfaction I would of course lock it down and statically assign the params. Thanks.

Comment: using permitted/declared params is better than using the model-based approach, more flexible at least. the caveat is like with strong params in Rails, it's tempting to just permit everything ;) but if this is just to get you going temporarily, it's all good

Comment: now the gem's name is `'hashie-forbidden_attributes'`